# Pass String from thymeleaf to controller

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I need pass String from the text area to doc variable in the controller. Please help.

HTML:

```
<div>
<textarea rows="10" cols="100" name="description"></textarea>
button class="button" onclick="window.location.href ='/send';">Send</button>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
@GetMapping("/send")
public String send(String doc) {

    service.sendDoc(doc);

    return "mainpage";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use post method:

```
 <form action="/send" method="POST">
        <textarea rows="10" cols="100" name="description"></textarea>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
 </form >
```

contorller:

```
@PostMapping("/send")
public String send(@RequestParam("description") String description) {

    service.sendDoc(description);
    return "mainpage";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

to getting data from front end by using GET method is a bad decision.....
by the way you can try this code

```
<form action="/send" method="GET">
    <textarea rows="10" cols="100" name="description"></textarea>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form >
```

controller code like this

```
@GetMapping("/send")
public String send(HttpServletRequest request) {

    String doc= request.getParameter("description");
    service.sendDoc(doc);

    return "mainpage";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found answer to this question:

Get value from Thymeleaf to Spring Boot

```
<form th:action="@{/send}" method="get">
   <textarea  th:name="doc" rows="10" cols="100" name="doc"></textarea>
   <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>


@GetMapping("/send")
public String send(@RequestParam(name="doc", required = false) String doc) {
    //change required = false as per requirement
    System.out.println("Doc: "+doc);
    return "textarea-input";
}
```

Note: use "th:field" for Entity/Model